# Python incremental iterating loop

Tags: python, loops, iteration

This is my code

```
for i in range(0,5):
        intl = i
        print(intl)
        intn = i+1
        print(intn)    
        i+=1
        print("---------")
```

What I am getting as the output is the following.

```
0
1
---------
1
2
---------
2
3
---------
3
4
---------
4
5
---------
```

Instead of that, I need to get;

```
0
1
---------
2
3
---------
4
5
---------
```

Comment: You're changing the value of i (which is set by the for loop) inside the for loop. That won't work. If you remove that line everything will work just the same way as before.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I made a mistake. What you are looking for is the step parameter of `range()` like this:

```
for i in range(0,5,2):
        intl = i
        print(intl)
        intn = i+1
        print(intn)    
        print("---------")
```

Now, for every loop it will skip one number (so i=0, then i=2, then i=4). When modifiying the variable `i` within a for loop, you will change the local version of `i` that is active in the current loop. Python doesn't actually use `i` to get the next item from a itterable, and thus manually changing it doesn't do anything for your loop.

Comment: No, I still get the same output.. :/

Comment: But this is because the range is (0,6). This range will differ based on another variable. So I cant manually give the range. Instead, I'm substituting that variable for the range. If that's the case, this won't work. 

for i in range(gri_tables.n): 
intl = i

Comment: @PranavHosangadi fair point, I have changed my answer and gave some more explanation, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
for i in range(0, 5, 2):
    intl = i
    intn = i+1
    print(intl)
    print(intn)    
    print("---------")
```

Now the range function has a step of 2. The step is the difference between each number. By default, it's 1.

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    print(i)
```

Returns:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

```
for i in range(0, 5, 2):
    print(i)
```

Returns:

```
0
2
4
```

In your code, you did this:

```
i+=1
```

This doesn't work because the variable i is set by the for loop in each iteration. This means that no matter what you do with the i variable, in the next iteration it will be 1 more than last time.

Answer (score -1):

This code prints `'-------'` whenever the next value of `i` is divisible by 2.

```
x = 5

for i in range(0, x+1):
    print(i)
    if (i+1) % 2 == 0:
        print('---------')
```

Comment: But this is because the range is (0,6). This range will differ based on another variable. So I cant manually give the range. Instead, I'm substituting that variable for the range. If that's the case, this won't work.

for i in range(gri_tables.n):
    intl = i

Comment: well, if it differ based on a variable 'x' you can do, for i in range(0, x+1)